# Rails remove certain params from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the best method for removing certain params from a url? For example I'm looking to change:

www.testsite.com/blog?blog_id=1582

to

www.testsite.com/blog/1582

```
<%= link_to list.blog_name, blog_blogs_path(blog_id: list.blog_id) %>
```

Comment: You should change it in your route

Comment: change the routes for that like '/controller-name/blog/:id' => 'controller-name#blog'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the link a variable and then carry out a string substitution

```
myString.gsub("?blod_id=", "/")
```

Comment: This worked and add re routing the path to get '/blogs/blog/:blog_id', :to => "blogs#blog"

Answer (score 1):

1. I would double check your path as typically when linking to a direct
   item it is singular and not plural.
2. You just need the ID to be passed into the path

Example:

```
<%= link_to list.blog_name, blog_blog_path(list.blog_id) %>
```

Note the path is now: blog_blog_path (no s)

Comment: Upvoted - this is one of those cases where the question really *does* seem to be a case of "you're holding it wrong". To user3373464 - have a careful read here, it's _well_ worth your time: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "blogs/index/#{list.blog_id}" %>
```